# how to change default values for .columnconfigure() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application made up of Frames, Frames in Frames and Labels in Frames. There is quite a lot of them and I am looking for a way to modify some of the default values.

I am particularly interested in modifying `.columnconfigure()` since I call `.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` on each of the columns, in each frame. This does not help with the code cleanness.

Is there a way to set this behavior (ability to expand) globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the defaults. You can easily write your own grid function to automatically configure the weight of each column. You could do this by subclassing `Frame`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you - this is extremely useful. Reading further on the subject and particularly [one of your previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300072/tkinter-inherit-from-frame-or-not) I will completely redesign my application.

Answer (score -1):

You can always do it in a loop

```
elements = [col0, col1, col2]
for element in elements:
    element.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: yes, that would work but my widgets are not organized in a list or dict - so there is no way to loop though them (the `Frame`s, for instance, are assigned to standalone variables)