# Tkinter gui loginsystem in python getting not deffined errors using .get()

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python login system I have attempted to built when I run the check on the user name and password I receive this error : http://pastebin.com/0DPAWx18

I was wondering if it because it is in a another function but I then put it in main as well and that just gave me errors

```
import tkinter
import time

def main():
    global window
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Login")
    window.minsize(300,150)
    window.configure(background="#7AC5CD")
    userlbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username")
    userlbl.pack()
    userinp = tkinter.Entry(window)
    userinp.pack()
    pwlbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password")
    pwlbl.pack()
    userpw = tkinter.Entry(window)
    userpw.pack()
    submitbtn = tkinter.Button(text="Submit username and password here", command=check)
    submitbtn.pack()

def check():
    username = userinp.get()
    password = userpw.get()    
    if username == 1234:
        GD_USER = tkinter.Label(window, text="Correct user name")
        GD_USER.pack()
    else:
        BD_USER = tkinter.Label(window, text="Bad username")
        BD_USER.pack()

    if password == 'test':
        GD_PASS = tkinter.Label(window, text="Correct password")
        GD_PASS.pack()
        entry_YES()
        return
    else:
        BD_PASS = tkinter.Label(window, text="wrong password")

    window.mainloop()


def entry_NO():
    print("access denied")
    time.sleep(5)
    close_window
    return



def entry_YES():
    print("Access granted please wait")


def close_window():
    window.destry()
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's is because you define `userinp` in the `main` function's scope, so it isn't defined the `check` function. You could make `userinp` and `userpw` global, or you could make your app into a class like this, which makes variable passing a lot easier through self.

The `__init__` function is called when the class is called, so that can be used as 'main'.
I've put pretty much everything in `self`, which isn't necessary,  but can be useful if you'd want to change any of the created widgets further on in a new function.
The `update()` function is needed to pack the labels before sleeping.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Login")
        self.window.minsize(300,150)
        self.window.configure(background="#7AC5CD")
        self.userlbl = tk.Label(self.window, text="Username")
        self.userlbl.pack()
        self.userinp = tk.Entry(self.window)
        self.userinp.pack()
        self.pwlbl = tk.Label(self.window, text="Password")
        self.pwlbl.pack()
        self.userpw = tk.Entry(self.window)
        self.userpw.pack()
        self.submitbtn = tk.Button(text="Submit username and password here", command=self.check)
        self.submitbtn.pack()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def check(self):
        self.username = self.userinp.get()
        self.password = self.userpw.get()    
        if self.username == '1234':
            self.GD_USER = tk.Label(self.window, text="Correct user name")
            self.GD_USER.pack()
        else:
            self.BD_USER = tk.Label(self.window, text="Bad username")
            self.BD_USER.pack()

        if self.password == 'test':
            self.GD_PASS = tk.Label(self.window, text="Correct password")
            self.GD_PASS.pack()
            self.entry_YES()
        else:
            self.BD_PASS = tk.Label(self.window, text="Wrong password")
            self.BD_PASS.pack()
            self.window.update()
            self.entry_NO()

    def entry_NO(self):
        print("Access denied, wait 5 seconds to try again")
        time.sleep(5)

    def entry_YES(self):
        print("Access granted please wait")

    def close_window(self):
        window.destroy()

App()
```

For more info on making your app into a class read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300072/tkinter-inherit-from-frame-or-not) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/python-tkinter-program-structure) question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response proved very usefull